# Space between sign and value for negative values

Tags: php, twig

I have negative decimal value like

> '-1.02'

i want space between sign and value like

> '- 1.02'

is there any possibilities in twig

For Now i'm trying  split as array `{% set foo = "-1.02"|split('') %}` and i trying to join with space But i think its not a right way.

Please suggest me

Comment: echo wordwrap('-1.02' , 1 , ' ' , true );

Comment: Are you going to make any calculations with this afterwards?

Comment: @Peter Only for display no further calculations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with the `replace` filter.

```
{{ '-1.02'|replace({'-': '- '}) }}
//outputs
- 1.02
```

See [this](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html) documentation entry.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Twig, but in PHP:

```
$value = -1.02;
echo str_replace('-', '- ', $value);
```